# OrderItem get_total() returns lower value than $order_item->get_product()->get_price() * quantity

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a weird issue. I am looping through an orders items, like so:

```
foreach($order->get_items() as $order_item) {
```

However, the price is: `7400` and there is `2` of them, but the `get_total()` returns `11840` instead of the expected `14800` - how come?

```
$order_item->get_product()->get_price() // returns 7400
$order_item->get_quantity() // returns 2
$order_item->get_total() // returns 11840 (expected is 14800)
```

Comment: The amount paid for the order item is completely independent of the product price. The items could have been cheaper when the order was made, or the order was programatically made with a different total. You can't rely on the product price to determine the amount paid for an order item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem seems to be related to missing tax or (and) to applied coupon discount.**

The `WC_Order_Item_Product` method [`get_total()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html#_get_total) is the ***discounted*** line item total ***without taxes***. In this case when a coupon is used, the discount is applied to the item depending of the coupon type and restrictions.

The `WC_Order_Item_Product` method [`get_subtotal()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html#_get_subtotal) is the **non** discounted line item total **without taxes**.

When there is no discount (no coupon applied), [`get_total()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html#_get_total) and [`get_subtotal()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html#_get_subtotal) have the same value.

So in your case, you may need to **add the taxes** using one of this `WC_Order_Item_Product` methods:

- [`get_total_tax()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html#_get_total_tax) method as discounted line item tax total
- [`get_subtotal_tax()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html#_get_subtotal_tax) method as **non** discounted line item tax total

and **to sum them** with the corresponding total **to get the line item total with tax** like:

```
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    $item_total = $item->get_total() + $item->get_total_tax(); // Discounted total with tax
}
```

or

```
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    $item_total = $item->get_subtotal() + $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // NON discounted total with tax
}
```

So this time you will get the correct amount.

---

**Related:** [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: Stumbled upon this issue again a few months later (now), and it really fixed my issue. Thanks a lot :>